# Object reference not set to an instance of an object em retorno de procedure

Tags: c#

Tenho uma procedure que retorna valor, porém quando chega no ExecuteScalar() do c# ele me retorna o erro `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`

A procedure está certinha

```
            private string IdentificaPat()
            {
                db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                string retorno;
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_InsertContratoGestores"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        retorno = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                if(retorno == "vazio")
                {
                    return "Vazio";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Sem novos contratos";
                }

                db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
                db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
            }
```

Comment: provavelmente seu `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` está retornando **NULL** e dá esse erro por conta do `ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Vejo que está utilizando o EF6, então você pode simplificar esta chamada para.:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Sp_InsertContratoGestores");
```